# Finding the $n$th term of some sequences given by its few first terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Does anyone know how to find the $n$th term of the following sequences:

$(1)\ $ $1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,....\\$

$(2)\ $1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,....\ $

$(3)\ $ $1,0,-1/2,0,1/3,0,-1,4,0,...\\$

$(4)\ $ $1,0,3/2,0,2/3,0,5/4,0,4/5,0,7/6,...$

I managed to get the first one which is $z_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n)$ where $a_n=\frac{1}{2}(1^n+(-1)^n)$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{2}(i^n+(-i)^n)$. anyone has an idea how to get the other sequences?

Comment: I use the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

Comment: @EricTowers: Thanks a lot for sharing the link with me! Very helpful! But for some reason, I couldn't get the formula!

Comment: (2) has period 8 hence is a linear combination of the sequences $(z^n)$ where $z$ are the 8th roots of unity. (3) and (4) are different in nature from (1) and (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to look at the 3rd one.

$1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots$ would be $1/n$.

$1,-1/2,1/3,-1/4,\dots$ would be $(-1)^{n-1}(1/n)$.

$1,0,-1/2,0,1/3,0,-1/4,\dots$, well, the nonzero terms are $(-1)^{(n-1)/2}{2\over n+1}$ so we can go with $$(-1)^{(n-1)/2}{1-(-1)^n\over n+1}$$ This can probably be simplified. But the main idea is to take it a piece at a time, building up to the sequence you want by way of simpler ones. Can you use these same ideas to do the 4th question?

Answer (score 1):

671958

## 1

If $n\equiv{0}\mod{4}$, then
....member = 1
else
....member = 0
endif

## 2

If $n\equiv{0}\mod{8}$, then
....member = 1
elseif $n\equiv{4}\mod{8}$ then
....member = -1
else
....member = 0
endif

## 3

NOTA BENE: I assume this one had a typo.
if $n\equiv{1}\mod{2}$ then
....member = 0
else
....if $n\equiv{0}\mod{4}$ then
........member = $\frac2{n+2}$
....else
........member = $-\frac2{n+2}$ (NOT an error!)
....endif
endif

## 4

if n = 0 then 
....member = 1 
else 
....if $n\equiv{1}\mod{2}$ then 
........member = 0 
....else 
........if $n\equiv{2}\mod{4}$ then
............member = ${{n+4}\over{n+2}}$ 
........else 
............member = $n\over{n+2}$ (NOT an error!) 
........endif 
....endif 
endif

Comment: Somehow, I don't think this is the kind of answer OP is looking for.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I do apologize. I'm quite new to this. Should I withdraw my answer? With all respect, Donn [user94874]

Comment: No need to apologize, no need to delete.